# How to Compute a Database Column in .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a Database named CarsType.accdb there are four fields in the data base Item_Name, Item_Num, Item_Qty, Item_Cost.

I am able to get the database to display my data in VisualBasic but I am not sure how to get the total cost to appear in my label (lblTotalCost).  I prefer doing it in VB versus writing in my access program.  All I am wanting to do it multiply `item_qty * Item_Cost`  How would I go about doing that?

```
Public Class frmCarInventory

    Private Sub CarInventoryBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CarInventoryBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.CarInventoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.CarDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmCarInventory_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'CarDataSet.CarInventory' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.CarInventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CarDataSet.CarInventory)


        Try
            Me.CarInventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CarDataSet.CarInventory)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("The Database Files is Unavailable", , "Error")
        End Try



    End Sub

    Private Sub btnComputeTheTotalValueOfInventory_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnComputeTheTotalValueOfInventory.Click


        Dim strSql As String = "SELECT * FROM CarType "

        'strPath provides the database type and path of the CarType database.
        Dim strPath As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 ;" & "Data Source=..\CarType.accdb"
        Dim odaInventory As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSql, strPath)
        Dim DatCost As New DataTable
        Dim intCount As Integer
        Dim decTotalCost As Decimal = 0D

        'The DataTable name datCost is filled with the data
    odaInventory.Fill(DatCost)

        'The connection to the databsise is disconnected
        odaInventory.Dispose()

        For intCount = 0 To DatCost.Rows.Count - 1
            decTotalCost += Convert.ToDecimal(DatCost.Rows(intCount)("Total Inventory  Cost"))
        Next

        Me.lblTotalCost.Visible = True
        Me.lblTotalCost.Text = "El Value " & decTotalCost.ToString("C")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Would this be handled like an sql satement?

Comment: If you want an answer that will help you, you will need to post the code you are using to display the data you are able to display. There are too many possible ways to display data, and to get a response that will help you, we need to see how _you_ do it.

Comment: I think we need to see a little of your code, otherwise we can only give you a general answer.

Comment: I submitted all the code for my program..  Be kind:) I am not a programmer but learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new `System.Data.DataColumn` to a `System.Data.DataTable`, you can specify an expression, thus creating a computed column. In C# the syntax to do this is:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("total_cost", typeof(double), "item_qty * item_cost");
```

The syntax to do this in VB.NET will be quite similar, but I've left it as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It took a little bit a thankin... but I got it. Thanks for the tip put in the right mindset.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could just use something like this?

```
Dim TotalCost As String

TotalCost = Me![item_qty] * Me![item_cost]

Me![lblTotalCost].Caption = TotalCost
```